# Switching from Win7 to Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: 12.04, 10.04

I'm in the process of backing up my assorted junk and just wanting to if I can download all my stuff from SkyDrive once I've installed Ubuntu. I plan on using SD and Ubuntu One to get my files across because I don't have enough USB or blank discs to do it that way and I don't have any external HDDs to use either.

I tried the LiveUSB version of 12.04 but all I got was a black screen that did nothing, not even showing my cursor but I got 10.04 working and I would like to know if I would be able to update to the latest without losing anything and if it still didn't work or gave me the same black screen, would I be able to revert back to my USB install of 10.04 again without losing any data.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am having trouble reading your question, so I assume that you are inquiring about SkyDrive support. You can do that using SMEstorage as a bridge:

First, install Ubuntu, following [these guidelines](https://askubuntu.com/a/152902/54298).

1. Download the SMEStorage application from http://smestorage.com/files/5dd8762105116876fdea9b87277e18b7.deb
2. Double-click it, and install it using Software Centre.
3. Register at http://smestorage.com/?p=uregister&pa_id=48. The free package will be fine as it offers all you need.
4. Open SME storage Explorer by searching it from the dash and supply your SMEstorage credentials.
5. Click the icon with the two yellow cylinders(I believe it's the rightmost icon on the toolbar) and select Skydrive from the list. Supply your login information.
6. To mount it so you can copy data from it easily, open SME Storage client by searching it in the dash.
7. Pick a location(`/home/[your username]/smestorage`) is fine, and then by opening your home folder and going to the location where you mounted it, you can copy data to your hard disk.

   If you have any trouble related to opening some files, I can help. Just leave a comment(That can be done even with 1 reputation for your posts and answers thereof)

<sub>Source: http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/12/mount-map-microsoft-skydrive-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/</sub>